# How do I add a language in FreeBSD?

Tags: shell, terminal, freebsd, unicode

Hello I want to add the Armenian language in FreeBSD. Here are my configs

## /etc/login.conf

```
armenian|Armenian Users Accounts:\
        :charset=ARMSCII-8:\
        :lang=hy_AM.ARMSCII-8:\
        :tc=default:
```

Execute `cap_mkdb /etc/login.conf`

## /home/david/.login_conf

```
me:\
        :charset=ARMSCII-8:\
        :lang=hy-AM.ARMSCII-8:
```

## /etc/ttys

```
console none                            unknown off secure
#
ttyv0   "/usr/libexec/getty Pc"         xterm   on  secure
  #Virtual terminals
ttyv1   "/usr/libexec/getty Pc"         xterm   on  secure
ttyv2   "/usr/libexec/getty Pc"         xterm   on  secure
ttyv3   "/usr/libexec/getty Pc"         xterm   on  secure
ttyv4   "/usr/libexec/getty Pc"         xterm   on  secure
ttyv5   "/usr/libexec/getty Pc"         xterm   on  secure
ttyv6   "/usr/libexec/getty Pc"         xterm   on  secure
ttyv7   "/usr/libexec/getty Pc"         xterm   on  secure
ttyv8   "/usr/local/bin/xdm -nodaemon"  xterm   off secure
  #Serial terminals
  #The 'dialup' keyword identifies dialin lines to login, fingerd etc.
ttyu0   "/usr/libexec/getty 3wire"      vt100   onifconsole secure
ttyu1   "/usr/libexec/getty 3wire"      vt100   onifconsole secure
ttyu2   "/usr/libexec/getty 3wire"      vt100   onifconsole secure
ttyu3   "/usr/libexec/getty 3wire"      vt100   onifconsole secure
  # Dumb console
dcons   "/usr/libexec/getty std.9600"   vt100   off secure
```

## /etc/rc.conf

```
mousechar_start=3
keymap="hy.armscii8"
scrnmap="armscii8-r2cp866"
font8x16="armscii8-8x16"
font8x14="armscii8-8x14"
font8x8="armscii8-8x8"
```

## /usr/share/syscons/fonts/*

```
-r--r--r--  1 root  wheel   5067 Aug  8  2016 armscii8-8x14.fnt
-r--r--r--  1 root  wheel   5775 Aug  8  2016 armscii8-8x16.fnt
-r--r--r--  1 root  wheel   2949 Aug  8  2016 armscii8-8x8.fnt
```

Please help.When I am typing in armenian shows ???????.What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: More to the point, what makes you think it isn't working?

Answer (score 5):

The problem was solved,solution is to add several lines in `/etc/login.conf`:

```
    :charset=UTF-8:\
    :lang=en_US.UTF-8:\
```

Thanks to everyone ))

Comment: For more information, read https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/using-localization.html

Comment: Depending on your specific situation, you may want to be setting the LANG environment variable.  This can be done with `export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"` (or whichever language you prefer).  You can add this to your `~/.profile` or similar if you want it to be set every time you open a login shell.